# How to dismiss an alert in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I need to have a sort of "blocked alert" that can't be dismissed by the user until some event occurs. So, I created the alert and removed all the buttons from it:

```
Alert waitingAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
waitingAlert.setTitle("Proposta Inviata");
waitingAlert.getButtonTypes().setAll();

waitingAlert.setHeaderText("La proposta è stata inviata a " + trade.getPlayer2Name());
waitingAlert.showAndWait();
```

Then, I need to dismiss it when a particular event occurs. I just tried doing it this way:

```
waitingAlert.close();
```

But it doesn't work.

**Edit**
The panel is shown when an user wants to send a request to another user in the network that needs to be accepted or refused. The principle is that the UI gets blocked until the other user says if he has accepted or refused the request. The request is send through a remote method invokation through a ring network. When I receive the response I want to close dismiss the panel.

Comment: `showAndWait()` blocks execution until the window is closed, so if the call to `close()` comes after that, there's basically no way it can be reached. You probably need to be a bit clearer about what's actually happening: are you doing some background process and want to close the alert when it's complete? If so, show how you have set up the threading. If it's not that, then what? Perhaps [edit] your question with more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a dialog that can't be dismissed by the user, but wait on a process, you will need to use dialog.show() as noted by James_D.

However, without buttons, the dialog actually will not close and you need to force it.

```
//for example
dialog.getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
dialog.hide();
dialog.getButtonTypes().remove(ButtonType.CANCEL);
```

This will allow you to close a dialog which has no buttons.